# Power BI group by calculation

Tags: powerbi, dax

I would like to take `VarA` for the first observation in a group and subtract from it `VarB` for the last observation in the group.  The layout is below. I want `Result` and `Group` is my group by variable. `Index` is a unique ordering variable that is an integer increasing by 1 down the whole column.

```
VarA  VarB  Group  Result    Index
 10     11    1   (10-7=3)   1
 11      4    1   (10-7=3)   2
...
 12     7     1   (10-7=3)   5
 9     11     2   (9-7=2)    6
 13      4    2   (9-7=2)    7
...
 11     7     2   (9-7=3)    11
```

Comment: What do you mean by "first" and "last"?

Comment: First observation in the group (first row) and last observation in the group (last row)

Comment: There is no such thing as "first row" or "last row" in power bi. You must define what order means.

Comment: Order? group sizes vary so i was saying first and last to keep it general

Comment: It's not so simple. You need to provide a field that defines order of an observation within a group. For example, it can be a timestamp - date/time an observation was recorded. Then first observation is defined by MIN(Timestamp). Or, you can use an index that refrects observation recording sequence. Then first  observation is defined by MIN(Index). Otherwise, PowerBI can't tell what's first - just because you **see** it first in the data table, does not mean anything (unlike in Excel, where your order is defined by row number - in PowerBI, there are no row numbers!).

Comment: ah ha, yes, i do have a column that is ordered.  call it VarE.  I converted a datetime stamp to integers so it is just an integer increasing by one the enitre column

Comment: Ok, great! Now please update your question :)

Comment: updated post. should be good to go, thanks for pointing out the issue with the missing ordering variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to calculate the maximal and minimal index values per group and then look up the values in the corresponding rows:

```
Result = 
    VAR CurrGroup = Table1[Group]
    VAR MaxIndex = CALCULATE(MAX(Table1[Index]), ALL(Table1), Table1[Group] = CurrGroup)
    VAR MinIndex = CALCULATE(MIN(Table1[Index]), ALL(Table1), Table1[Group] = CurrGroup)
    RETURN LOOKUPVALUE(Table1[VarA], Table1[Index], MinIndex) -
           LOOKUPVALUE(Table1[VarB], Table1[Index], MaxIndex)
```